# Getting crashes with different length strings and unsure why

Tags: c

I need to take a string which will only contain hex digits and convert it into a int array of 40 where each space contains one digit from the string, the array needs to be populated backwards so the least significant digit is the first spot of the array.

If the string does not contain 40 digits then it needs to padd the right amount of zeros to the end of the array.

Here is the code i am working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char *str = "0123456789aBcdef0123456";

  printf("%s\n", str);

  char *s = strdup(str);

  int i = 0;
  while (s[i]) {
    if (s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122)
      s[i] -= 32;
    i++;
  }
  int amount = 40 - i, under40 = 0, k = 39;

  printf("%s\n   amount:%d\n", s, amount);

  int *digits = malloc(sizeof(int) * 40);

  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

    if (amount > 0) {
      digits[k] = 0;
      under40 = 1;
      amount--;
      i--;
    } else {
      switch (s[i]) {
      case 'A':
        digits[k] = 10;
        break;

      case 'B':
        digits[k] = 11;
        break;

      case 'C':
        digits[k] = 12;
        break;

      case 'D':
        digits[k] = 13;
        break;

      case 'E':
        digits[k] = 14;
        break;

      case 'F':
        digits[k] = 15;
        break;

      default:
        digits[k] = s[i] - 48;
      }
    }
    k--;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    printf("%i ", digits[i]);

  if (under40 == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nUnder 40 digits passed\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

With the current string, at the first line in main, the program crashes but any string larger then this one it is fine and i'm really not sure why. There are also a few instances with shorter strings that do not crash.

This is what really is confusing as **I don't know why some lengths are working and some are not**. For example 0123456789aBcdef0123456789869679866896AAAAdddd is fine and 01234 is fine.

Comment: Have you ran a debugger through the code? What error do you get or what section crashes?

Comment: `i < 40 ;` ... `switch (s[i])` ... but `"0123456789aBcdef0123456"` length is `23`.

Comment: modifying `i` (`i--;`) in your look potentially makes the loop run more than 40 times, leaving the possibility of `k` to be negative. Don't use 2 indexes, and don't change value of i within loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the length of the string is less than 40, your loop actually runs more than 40 times because `i` is decremented as long as `amount` is positive.  As a result, `k` becomes negative and you end up writing before the start of your `digits` array.  Reading and writing outside the bounds of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Your loop needs to check the value of `k` to ensure it remains non-negative:

```
for (i = 0; i < 40 && k >= 0; i++) {
```

A better way to do this would be to decrement `k` in the loop and increment `i` only when needed.

```
for (i = 0, k = 39; k >= 0; k--) {
    if (amount > 0) {
      digits[k] = 0;
      under40 = 1;
      amount--;
      // don't decrement i here
    } else {
        switch (s[i]) {
            ...
        }
        i++;  // increment here instead
    }
    // no need to decrement k here
}
```

Also, you can simplify the `switch` into a single conditional (assuming ASCII encoding where 'A' - 'F' are sequential):

```
digits[k] = (s[i] >= 10) ? s[i] - 'A' + 10 : s[i] - '0';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance , and also thanks to whoever formatted my question better, read a lot of helpful solutions on here but first time ever posting something myself